# Convert Microsoft snp to pdf

Tags: java

Can any body tell me is there any API in Java (1.5) which converts a Microsoft [SNP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNP_file_format) file to PDF format please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a command line tool (Snp2Pdf.exe) to convert SNP docs to PDF format. Where in we can invoke the same using Process and run the program.